# Partitioning on non-unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that lists events, operations in the events and the time of each operation. Event ID is not unique, as it is the same event, just happening on different times. Operations might differ for the same type of the event. The same event never runs twice in a row).

I want to populate three new columns as per given example. This will allow me to run analysis on the separate events as I'll be able to generate a unique "Event" ID.

Edit:
I already tried PARTITION function based on event and it haven't worked as SQL server assumes two events (A and B) and therefore gives the same start date to all "A" events, even if in reality I need to show them as separate events with different start dates.

[image: Example]

Thank you!

Comment: "I already tried PARTITION function" - show us!

Comment: Just scrolled my results table and realised that even my row number giving function doesn't work as commented above. Due to non unique Event IDs, SQL server is partitioning this into two sets, while I need to identify 3 separate events.

Answer (score 1):

This is just window functions:

```
select t.*,
       min(operationtime) over (partition by event) as event_start_time,
       max(operationtime) over (partition by event) as event_end_time,
       concat(event, '-', min(operationtime) over (partition by event)) as event_id
from t;
```

Actually, for the event id, you probably want something like:

```
       concat(event, '-', convert(varchar(255), min(operationtime) over (partition by event), 101)) as event_id
```

or whatever format for the date you really want.  I recommend YYYY-MM-DD as a date format.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it won't work. Tried already. Because of non unique Event IDs - SQL server is partitioning this into two sets of data (A and B). However I need to see three events (A, B, A) with individual start dates. The suggested solution would give the start date of the first event,  to events 1 & 3, as they share same ID.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this as a gaps-and-island problem, where you want to build groups of consecutive daily events.

One option uses the difference between row numbers to identify the groups:

```
select 
    t.*,
    min(operation_time) over(partition by event, rn1 - rn2) event_start_time,
    max(operation_time) over(partition by event, rn1 - rn2) event_end_time,
    concat(event, '-', min(operation_time) over(partition by event, rn1 - rn2)) event_id
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(order by operation_time) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by event order by operation_time) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
order by operation_time
```

If there is always one and only one event per day, as showned in your sample data, then one `row_number()` is sufficient, along with date arithmetics:

```
select
    t.*,
    min(operation_time) over(partition by event, grp) event_start_time,
    max(operation_time) over(partition by event, grp) event_end_time,
    concat(event, '-', min(operation_time) over(partition by event, grp)) event_id
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        dateadd(
            day,
            - row_number() over(partition by event order by operation_time),
            operation_time
        ) grp
from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: Thank you - will try the first solution. The second one won't work as, unfortunately, the same events can happen on the same day. Just tried to give a more simplified example of the actual problem. The only saving grace is that they can't run one after another one.

Comment: Thank you. I did have problems trying to implement the code. But that's probably just me. Thank you very much for giving my problem an "industry standard name" - gaps-and-island. Wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

This approach creates the event group explicitly, then it uses a windowing query very similar to the other answers.  I created a simple sample table to show results.

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTEST;
go
select * INTO #tTEST from (values 
('A', 'X', '2020-01-08'),
('A', 'Z', '2020-02-08'),
('B', 'X', '2020-03-08'),
('B', 'Z', '2020-04-08'),
('A', 'X', '2020-05-08'),
('A', 'Z', '2020-06-08')) V([Event], [Operation], operation_time);
```

Query

```
;with
grp_cte as (
    select t.*, case when lag([Event], 1, 0) over (order by operation_time) != [Event] then 1 else 0 end grp_ind
    from #tTEST t),
event_grp_cte as (
    select gc.*, sum(grp_ind) over (order by operation_time) EventGroup
    from grp_cte gc)
select 
    t.*,
    min(operation_time) over(partition by EventGroup) event_start_time,
    max(operation_time) over(partition by EventGroup) event_end_time,
    concat(event, '-', min(operation_time) over(partition by EventGroup)) event_id
from event_grp_cte t
order by operation_time;
```

Results

```
Event   Operation   operation_time  grp_ind EventGroup  rn1 rn2 event_start_time    event_end_time  event_id
A       X       2020-01-08  1   1   1   1   2020-01-08  2020-02-08  A-2020-01-08
A       Z       2020-02-08  0   1   2   2   2020-01-08  2020-02-08  A-2020-01-08
B       X       2020-03-08  1   2   3   1   2020-03-08  2020-04-08  B-2020-03-08
B       Z       2020-04-08  0   2   4   2   2020-03-08  2020-04-08  B-2020-03-08
A       X       2020-05-08  1   3   5   3   2020-05-08  2020-06-08  A-2020-05-08
A       Z       2020-06-08  0   3   6   4   2020-05-08  2020-06-08  A-2020-05-08
```

Comment: This worked great - thank you very much! I did have come cases where the code broke, however it's due to additional complexity. Super neat solution. Thank you!